# Turn vector into division table R

Tags: r, pivot-table, division

I have 2 columns, one is Country and the other is Value

How can I make turn this table into a division table of sorts such that each value is divided by every other value and I would have the Country as rownames and column names, the values would be every possible division value. The picture describes what I'm trying to accomplish but in Excel. I would like to do this in R. Where the first table in transformed into the second table. I don't care to have the original values displayed in yellow only the division table.

[Transform top table into bottom table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo8lw.png)

I've tired many combinations of pivoting, joining, copying columns etc and get close but not the result I'm looking for. Is there a tidy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `outer`:

```r
x <- c(Argentina = 1.7, Australia = 5.5, Belgium = 0.5, Brazil = 8.7)
t(outer(x, x, `/`))
```

output

```r
          Argentina  Australia    Belgium    Brazil
Argentina 1.0000000  3.2352941 0.29411765  5.117647
Australia 0.3090909  1.0000000 0.09090909  1.581818
Belgium   3.4000000 11.0000000 1.00000000 17.400000
Brazil    0.1954023  0.6321839 0.05747126  1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = c(arg = 1.7, aus = 5.5, bel = 0.5, bra = 8.7)

y = outer(x, x, FUN = \(a,b) b/a)
y

#           arg        aus        bel       bra
# arg 1.0000000  3.2352941 0.29411765  5.117647
# aus 0.3090909  1.0000000 0.09090909  1.581818
# bel 3.4000000 11.0000000 1.00000000 17.400000
# bra 0.1954023  0.6321839 0.05747126  1.000000

cbind(c(NA, x), rbind(" " = x, y))

#               arg        aus        bel       bra
#      NA 1.7000000  5.5000000 0.50000000  8.700000
# arg 1.7 1.0000000  3.2352941 0.29411765  5.117647
# aus 5.5 0.3090909  1.0000000 0.09090909  1.581818
# bel 0.5 3.4000000 11.0000000 1.00000000 17.400000
# bra 8.7 0.1954023  0.6321839 0.05747126  1.000000
```